# Creating a Record Option on a PDF or Word Document

Tags: pdf, ms-word, adobe, ms-office, word-2013

I am going to preface this with the question on a more general scale then go on to explain my specific issue.

Is there a way to create a word document, pdf, or anything comparable that I could add a "Record Audio" button to that would save the audio with the file as well as all the other info that might on a pdf/word form?

I know that Adobe Pro has a leave audio comment option, but I am creating this for a user and I do  not want them to have to use that.  The reason I need this is that I currently have a form usually gets partially filled out and then passed on with a dictation that needs to be transcribed at a later time.  I am aiming to do this so that I can have the form and audio file linked and saved under one file.

If there is a way to leave the audio comment on a pdf with some javascript that is triggered by a button, I am perfectly okay with that I just have no clue how to program that (in terms of syntax, I am comfortable programming that isn't the problem lol).

I am also open to forms of documents other than pdf or word.  I only mentioned these as they are the industry standard, but if there is another file type that would work around this, I am more than glad to use it!

I am using word 2013 by the way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a TaskPane Addin that shows the audio controls. Once the recording is complete, the audio could be saved in the CustomXML parts in the document.
Then other users who receive the document and have your AddIn, will be able to listen to the recording.

Comment: Could you explain how I can go about this or link me to something?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have not verified it in-depth, but it would be possible to add a button to the PDF file which creates a Sound annotation. The user should be then automatically asked (via a dialog) to record it.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I have no clue how to go about this.  I haven't seen anything similar online.  Also, most of my programming experience has been in C, python, and VBA, so while I can write Javascript discovering something like this on my own would be unlikely.  Any ideas?